# Find and remove matching column values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe where occasionally the columns will have a wrong value that matches another column. It would look something like this:

```
| Date         | Latitude      |
| 2017-01-01   | 43.4553       |
| 2017-01-02   | 42.9399       |
| 2017-01-03   | 43.0091       |
| 2017-01-04   | 2017-01-04    |
```

Obviously, the last Latitude value is incorrect. I need to remove any and all rows that are like this. I thought about using `.isin()` but I can't seem to get it to work. If I try

```
df['Date'].isin(['Latitude'])
```

I get:

```
Column<(Date IN (Latitude))>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you're more comfortable with SQL syntax, here is an alternative way using a `pyspark-sql` condition inside the `filter()`:

```python
df = df.filter("Date NOT IN (Latitude)")
```

Or equivalently using [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where):

```python
df = df.where("Date NOT IN (Latitude)")
```