# Pyspark: How to remove an item from a collect_set?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, set, apache-spark-sql

In the following dataframe:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", "code1", "name"),
    ("a", "code1", "name2"),
    ("a", "code2", "name2"),
], ["id", "code", "name"])

df.show()
```

You can run this command to get a list of distinct values:

```python
df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_set("code")).show()

+---+-----------------+
| id|collect_set(code)|
+---+-----------------+
|  a|   [code2, code1]|
+---+-----------------+
```

How do you remove an item in the above collect_set? E.g. how to remove `'code2'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove an element from a Python list of lists in PySpark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624567/remove-an-element-from-a-python-list-of-lists-in-pyspark-dataframe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update for Spark 2.4+:** You can achieve this with [`array_remove`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_remove):

```python
df_grouped = df.groupby("id")\
    .agg(F.array_remove(F.collect_set("code"), "code2").alias("codes"))
```

---

**Original answer for Spark 2.3 and below**

AFAIK there is no way to dynamically [iterate over an `ArrayType()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993439/typeerror-column-is-not-iterable-how-to-iterate-over-arraytype), so if your data is already in an array you have two options:

**Option 1: Explode, Filter, Collect**

Use [`pyspark.sql.functions.explode()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode) to turn the elements of the array into separate rows. Then use [`pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.where) to filter out the desired values. Finally do a `groupBy()` and `collect_set()` to gather the data back into one row.

```python
df_grouped = df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_set("code").alias("codes"))
df_grouped.select("*", F.explode("codes").alias("exploded"))\
    .where(~F.col("exploded").isin(["code2"]))\
    .groupBy("id")\
    .agg(F.collect_set("exploded").alias("codes"))\
    .show()
#+---+-------+
#| id|  codes|
#+---+-------+
#|  a|[code1]|
#+---+-------+
```

**Option 2: Use a UDF**

```python
def filter_code(array):
    bad_values={"code2"}
    return [x for x in array if x not in bad_values]

filter_code_udf = F.udf(lambda x: filter_code(x), ArrayType(StringType()))
df_grouped = df.groupby("id").agg(F.collect_set("code").alias("codes"))
df_grouped.withColumn("codes_filtered", filter_code_udf("codes")).show()
#+---+--------------+--------------+
#| id|         codes|codes_filtered|
#+---+--------------+--------------+
#|  a|[code2, code1]|       [code1]|
#+---+--------------+--------------+
```

Of course, if you are starting from your original dataframe (before the `groupBy()` and `collect_set()`) you can just filter the desired values first:

```python
df.where(~F.col("code").isin(["code2"])).groupby("id").agg(F.collect_set("code")).show()
#+---+-----------------+
#| id|collect_set(code)|
#+---+-----------------+
#|  a|          [code1]|
#+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: is there a 'isnotin' command, I'm looking to filter one out of many. Regardless, it looks like the other two options work. Thanks!

Comment: @MicahPearce you just need to do the inverse of `isin()` - see the answers on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49992272/find-and-remove-matching-column-values-in-pyspark/50003173#50003173).

Comment: Ah, and that's what he did. That makes sense.

Comment: @MicahPearce also worth noting that using a `udf` is *usually* slower and to be avoided if possible.